# Crashlytics was applied to a project without an Android plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, crashlytics

I am working on an Ionic Cordova app that uses Cordova-fabric-plugin.
We have recently been having this error when building the app with Gradle, and we are not able to identify the cause:

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.fabric'] Error:(66, 0) Crashlytics was
>   applied to a project without an Android plugin. Please make sure the
>   Crashlytics plugin is applied after the appropriate Android plugin for
>   your project

Can someone help me here

Answer (score 3):

The problem with **cordova-android: 7.0.0** incompatibility of the plugin with **cordova-android platform 7.0.0** So I have downgraded version to **6.4.0**

Please run below command :

1. ionic cordova platform rm android
2. ionic cordova platform add **android@6.4.0**

Done! Solved my problem